# Wait until GPS location is retrived for ListActivity

Tags: android, multithreading, gps, listactivity

I am working on an Android project in which I am using GPS data for showing nearby Restaurants. On the server side, I have implemented the Haversine formula to get nearby Restaurants depending upon the longitude and latitude retrieved. But, I am having a problem as to how should I tell  my ListActivity class to wait until a non-zero GPS location is retrieved.

I checked similar questions, but they didn't provide any help for ListActivity. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

ListRestaurants code :

```
public class RestaurantList extends ListActivity  {

    private ResponseEntity<RestRestaurant[]> responseEntity;

    private OrderAdapter m_adapter;

    private ArrayList<RestRestaurant> m_orders = null;

    GPSTracker gps;

    double longitude, latitude;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restos);
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = StaticRestTemplate.getRest();
        final String restaurantList = StaticRestTemplate.baseURL+"getnearbyrestaurants";


        gps = new GPSTracker(RestaurantList.this);
        long TIMEOUT = 5000l; // 5 seconds
        long startTime = new Date().getTime();
        while (!gps.canGetLocation()) {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
            long difference = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
            if (TIMEOUT > difference) break;

        }
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       /* if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }*/



        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid);
                requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "json")));
                HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(restaurantList+"/"+longitude+"/"+latitude,
                        HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, RestRestaurant[].class);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setTitle("Loading");
        progress.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        progress.dismiss();
        RestRestaurant[] restRestaurantList = responseEntity.getBody();

        m_orders = new ArrayList<RestRestaurant>();
        this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_orders);

        for (RestRestaurant restRestaurant1 : restRestaurantList) {
            m_adapter.add(restRestaurant1);

        }

        setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
```

Now, as you can see in the thread, I am passing the longitude and latitude. I don't want to pass non-zero data there.

Here is the GPSTracker code I am using :

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

What I would like to do is ask user to turn on GPS and then only call the thread code and set the adapter. I am new to Android, please take that into consideration. Thank you.

Comment: u got this fixed??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while to wait until timeout or getting location

```
long TIMEOUT = 5000l; // 5 seconds

long startTime = new Date().getTime();
while (!gps.canGetLocation()) {
    gps.showSettingsAlert();
    long difference = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
    if (TIMEOUT > difference) break;
}

latitude = gps.getLatitude();
longitude = gps.getLongitude();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: For timeout, should I just use Thread.sleep(1000);  or something else?

Comment: I would recommend to read time before while, define a constant for timeout, and then check after each iteration....

Comment: Sorry, not working, the request is still going ahead. I dont know how. I am editing my main post to show how the code looks like now.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to properly implement onLocationChanged - this function will be called when you have a location. Once you get location with good precision, you can notify your main activity.
Of course, this should be running in a separate thread.

Comment: Can you tell me the changes needed in my code to achieve that. I have tried multiple stuff, but none of them seemed to work. Thanks a lot. :-)