# Taking a picture via camera and sending it to server in bytearray

Tags: java, android, spring, android-camera, imgscalr

I am working on an Andorid application in which I would like the user to take a picture and then to save it I am sending it over to the server. Now, I am sending the picture as a byte-array to the server. When I try to save the byte-array to a file as a PNG file, and then try to open the file, the image-viewer complains that the PNG has errors and cannot be displayed. The PNG file size was 122Kb.

When I tried to use Scalr library to resize the image, it says the image source cannot be null. Directly saving the byte-array is causing a corrupt PNG. How should I convert and send the file properly to server, so there are no errors. 
Here is the code for camera which I am using and sending it over.

```
public class AddPhotoForUser extends DrawerLoader {

    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 22;
    Button BtnSelectImage;
    private ImageView ImgPhoto;
    private static volatile Bitmap photo;
    private static volatile ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    final PersonServiceImpl personService = new PersonServiceImpl();

    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.upload_user_photo);

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);

        Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
        uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ImgPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPhotoImageView);
        BtnSelectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.userPhotoButtonSelect);
        BtnSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {

                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't load photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!(v == null)) {
                    uploadImage();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddPhotoForUser.this, RestaurantList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddPhotoForUser.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                            if (!(photo == null)) {
                                ImgPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
                                Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
                                uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't load photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void uploadImage() {

        if (!(photo == null)) {
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            personService.addUserProfilePhoto(byteArray);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the server side code to save the image to disk :

```
 @Override
    public Boolean updateProfilePhoto(byte[] photo) {
        Person person = getCurrentlyAuthenticatedPerson();
        try{
           InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
            image = Scalr.resize(image, Scalr.Method.QUALITY, 100, 100);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
            baos.flush();
            File file = new File(userImagePath);
            if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(userImagePath + person.getUserId()+".png"));
                outputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());
                outputStream.close();
            } else {
                File file1 = new File(userImagePath+person.getUserId()+".png");
                if (file1.exists()) {
                    try {
                        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                        outputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());
                        outputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                } else {
                   boolean result = file1.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("Result of file1 creation is "+result);
                    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                    outputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If I don't use the Scalr library, there are no errors, but its a corrupt file. Here is the Scalr error log :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: src cannot be null
    at org.imgscalr.Scalr.resize(Scalr.java:1564)
    at org.imgscalr.Scalr.resize(Scalr.java:1415)
    at com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl.updateProfilePhoto(PersonServiceImpl.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.updateProfilePhoto(Unknown Source)
    at com.journaldev.spring.Controller.PersonController.addProfilePhotoForUser(PersonController.java:100)
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

*Updated code*

```
public class AddPhotoForUser extends DrawerLoader {


    Button BtnSelectImage;
    private ImageView ImgPhoto;

    private static volatile ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    final PersonServiceImpl personService = new PersonServiceImpl();

    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private static final int CAMERA_PHOTO = 111;
    private Uri imageToUploadUri;

    Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.upload_user_photo);

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);

        Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
        uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ImgPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPhotoImageView);
        BtnSelectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.userPhotoButtonSelect);
        BtnSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {

                    captureCameraImage();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't load photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!(v == null)) {
                    uploadImage();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddPhotoForUser.this, RestaurantList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            }
        });

    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 12000000; // 12MP
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) >
                    IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }
            Log.d("", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

            Bitmap b = null;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

                // resize to desired dimensions
                int height = b.getHeight();
                int width = b.getWidth();
                Log.d("", "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

                double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                        / (((double) width) / height));
                double x = (y / height) * width;

                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,
                        (int) y, true);
                b.recycle();
                b = scaledBitmap;
                System.gc();
            } else {
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            in.close();

            Log.d("", "bitmap size - width: " + b.getWidth() + ", height: " +
                    b.getHeight());
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void captureCameraImage() {
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddPhotoForUser.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(imageToUploadUri != null){
                Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
                if(reducedSizeBitmap != null){
                    ImgPhoto.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
                    Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
                    uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        if(!(reducedSizeBitmap == null)){
            reducedSizeBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            this.personService.addUserProfilePhoto(byteArray);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Uploaded image screenshot]

Comment: Please note, on mobile I am able to see the photo in ImageView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `Bundle extras = data.getExtras();` in your `onActivityResult()` then it will return thumbnail image not actual image.

Here is code I have used for Capturing and Saving Camera Image then display it to `ImageView`. You can use according to your need.

You have to save Camera image to specific location then fetch from that location then convert it to byte-array.

Here is method for opening capturing camera image activity.

```
private static final int CAMERA_PHOTO = 111;
private Uri imageToUploadUri;

private void captureCameraImage() {
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
    }
```

then your `onActivityResult()` method should be like this.

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if(imageToUploadUri != null){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                    Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
                    if(reducedSizeBitmap != null){
                        ImgPhoto.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
                        Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
                          uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
        }
```

Here is `getBitmap()` method used in `onActivityResult()`. I have done all performance improvement that can be possible while getting camera capture image bitmap.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) >
                    IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }
            Log.d("", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

            Bitmap b = null;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

                // resize to desired dimensions
                int height = b.getHeight();
                int width = b.getWidth();
                Log.d("", "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

                double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                        / (((double) width) / height));
                double x = (y / height) * width;

                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,
                        (int) y, true);
                b.recycle();
                b = scaledBitmap;

                System.gc();
            } else {
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            in.close();

            Log.d("", "bitmap size - width: " + b.getWidth() + ", height: " +
                    b.getHeight());
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Here is method for uploading image to server.

```
/**
 * Upload Image to server
 *
 * @param file              image to be saved
 * @param compressorQuality quality of image
 * @return path of uploaded image in server
 */
private String uploadImage(Bitmap file, int compressorQuality) {
    String final_upload_filename = "demo_image.png";
    String response = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        URL url = new URL("image_upload_url");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", final_upload_filename);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"" + final_upload_filename + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        file.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, compressorQuality, dos);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            baos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        byte[] bytesReceived = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        is.close();
        response = new String(bytesReceived);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

You need to make upload script in backend server to store image data in particular folder.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, I have updated my main post and at bottom added the effective code. And also the screenshot when I open the image. For the server-side code, I have removed the Scalr library and I am directly saving the byte-array recieved, no luck unfortunately. Can you please check. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your app side code is ok . it might be issue of uploading image to server

Comment: I dont think so, as I am just sending the bytearray and saving it. Do you recommend using something else for transfer over the network?

Comment: You were right, there was something wrong on the server side. Now it works. Thanks a lot. Will mark this answer... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw, can you please check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199394/wait-until-gps-location-is-retrived-for-listactivity  . I have tried many ways, but it's not working, any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to create a file and save image on it and here's a code.

//method to save image in internal or external storage

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image,String imageName) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(imageName);
    if (pictureFile == null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
        return;
    } 
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }  
}
```

//method to create file to save image on it

```
private  File getOutputMediaFile(String imageName){
    //create folder with name FoursquareAPI
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/FoursquareAPI");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    } 
    File mediaFile;
        String mImageName= imageName +".png";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);  
    return mediaFile;
}
```