# Taking Picture via intent to internal (app) storage returns null for bitmap

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, internal-storage

The scope: I want to take a picture via intent and save the picture to the internal storage of my app.
Then I want to load a scaled version into a byte array (from inputstream), save this scaled image as byte array into SQLight.
After saving it to the database I want to delete the picture.

(This question only is about saving the image to internal storage, the scope is only here because there is always someone that ask about it)

The problem: I'm stuck at saving the picture to the internal storage.

I'll add examples from my debugging session as comments behind the variables to show the values i got while testing.

I have an ImageView which has an onClickListener that starts the takePictureIntent:

With following global attributes:

```
Uri mCurrentPhotoUri; //URI to file
File mCurrentPicture; //the current picture don't know if I need it somewhere but for complete understanding of code

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Intent for the on-board camera
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //device has camera
        if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                //create a file with path the code below
                photoFile = createImageFile(); //sets photoFile to: /data/data/my.app.project/app_photo/JPEG_20151105_092219_-1434131481.jpg
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //file has been created, set members and add Extra to intent, then start intent.
            if(photoFile != null) {
                mCurrentPicture = photoFile; // well, same as above
                mCurrentPhotoUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile); // this looks somehow wrong, but I don't know much about URIs: file:///data/data/my.app.project/app_photo/JPEG_20151105_092219_-1434131481.jpg
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile)); //same URI as above that extra should be needed to tell the cam that I don't want to save to the default path but my app path
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 10); //start the intent and use requestcode 10 for onActivityResult ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The creation of the file path:

```
//code from google developers with some changes. 
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()); //from today value: 20151105_092219
        String imageFilename = "JPEG_" + timestamp + "_"; // concat is this: JPEG_20151105_092219_
        File storageDir = this.getDir("photo", MODE_PRIVATE); //String path is: /data/data/my.app.project/app_photo
        storageDir.mkdirs();
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFilename, ".jpg", storageDir); //String path is: /data/data/my.app.project/app_photo/JPEG_20151105_092219_-1434131481.jpg
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath(); //here I put the absolute path into static mCurrentPhotoPath, concate with the "file:" from googledeveloper guide: file:/data/data/my.app.project/app_photo/JPEG_20151105_092219_-1434131481.jpg
        return image;
}
```

So the camera opens and I can take a picture and I'm ask if I want to save that picture (all from the build-in camera app, device is a samsung galaxy note).

Then my onActivityResult-Method is called:
I used data as parameter because I used the mini byte array for something, but with the custom storage this returns null **and it isn't used anymore**.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch(requestcode) {
            ...
            case 10:
                setImageView(ivPreview1, data, 0);
                ivPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            ...
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

Method setImageView:

```
private void setImageView(ImageView iv, Intent data, int index) {
        try {
            Uri u = mCurrentPhotoUri; //sets u to: file:///data/data/my.app.project/app_photo/JPEG_20151105_092219_-1434131481.jpg

            File file = new File(u.getPath()); //sets file to: /data/data/my.app.project/app_photo/JPEG_20151105_092219_-1434131481.jpg
            Bitmap bm = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
            int orientation = 0;
            if (file.exists()) { //this is true

                //found that somewhere in the developer training:
                ExifInterface exif = null;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(photoUri.getPath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(exif != null)
                    orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0); //is 0 (i didn't rotate the tablet)

                //resulution I want to resize the image to:
                int reqWidth = 960, reqHeight = 1280;

                //exchange values if orientation doesn't match landscape
                if (orientation == 0 || orientation == 270) {
                    int temp = reqWidth;
                    reqWidth = reqHeight;
                    reqHeight = temp;

                }
                //this I used before I changed to internal storage to change the size of the image code below
                bm = ImageManager.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(u.getPath(), reqWidth, reqHeight); // returns null because of this everything following is null too.

                if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 180 || orientation == 270) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    // rotate the Bitmap

                    if (orientation == 90)
                        matrix.postRotate(90F);
                    else if (orientation == 270)
                        matrix.postRotate(-90F);
                    else
                        matrix.postRotate(180F);

                    // recreate the new Bitmap
                    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0,
                            bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                }
                baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
            }

            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not take Photo: ", e);
        }
    }
```

The following methods that I used to decode the file (customisation of: http://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/DisplayingBitmaps.zip ):

**The line with BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options); also creates a log entry: D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null**

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filename,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    //this gets parameters:
    // reqHeight: 960, reqWidth: 1280 and filename: /data/data/my.app.project/app_photo/JPEG_20151105_092219_-1434131481.jpg

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options); // this adds outHeight and outWidth to -1 (variables from options) 
    //this also creates a log entry: D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;



    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
    return bmp;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight; //is -1
        final int width = options.outWidth; //is -1
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        //because its obviously smaller in both statements code will not be executed so it returns 1
        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }

            // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
            // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
            // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
            // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
            // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

            long totalPixels = width * height / inSampleSize;

            // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
            final long totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

            while (totalPixels > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
                totalPixels /= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
        // END_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
    }
```

I'm stuck at this for several days now I don't have any ideas that could solve my problem. This is also due to lack of android knowledge and the fact that i can't use emulators on my pc so i can't even look in the app folder to see if a picture was taken.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32245332/3702862

Comment: when your device is connected, try launching [Android Device Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html) from your IDE (you can access it from your SDK dir on your PC as well, somewhere under /tools I think, or somewhere else). This will allow you to access the device's storage.  Also, where do you get data of `data` in your `setImageView`? I may be blind, but can't seem to find it. :)

Comment: can't reedit my previous comment so disregard the last sentence :)

Comment: @Klotor i don't have a tool directory but the device has no root access to my knowledge i can't access the stuff in tha app folder (/data/)

Comment: @Rajesh do you mean the getBitmap method? and that i shall first open the file into a stream and not directly from file?

Comment: @Alcardis There is a possibility that the Android camera app cannot access your `storageDir` in `createImageFile` because it's `MODE_PRIVATE`, try replacing it with some external dir if you can, or something not private, and see if it works then

Comment: @Klotor i can try that later today. If the app directory is not possible i would like to use a directory from the internal storage of the device and not an external sdcard because the tablets will not have an external sdcard. Which android method do i need to acces the android storage so that i could use a folder i could see via usb access? I would want something like /storage/sdcard0/pictures/ but that would be an absolute path of my own device I think this won't work with devices from different manufacturers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the path for storing temporary image like below.which will return your app folder location.and add the permission as well.

```
 File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/"+"photo";
```

> Add uses-feature for camera access too.

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
```

Official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/camera/photobasics.html).

Comment: Okay i tested this it works, but with that all applications have acces to the directory if I'm not wrong because the permission for that directory are set like external directories? (Which in my case doesn't matter because i will delete the directory after useage) Just wan't to ask because always try to full understand what I'm doing.

Comment: does it really save on internal storage?

Comment: well i had to change it a little to:
File storageDir = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "photo");
this has in debugger the value: 
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my.app.project/files/photo